# Swift: Updated and got error: "cannot invoke '!=' with argument list of type.."

Tags: swift, xcode6

Everything was fine in Xcode beta 5 but now in full fledged Xcode I'm getting 2 similar errors in my App Delegate:

1. `"cannot invoke '!=' with argument list of type '(NSManagedObjectContext, NilLiteralConvertible')"`
2. `"cannot invoke '!=' with argument list of type '(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, NilLiteralConvertible')"`

I tried replacing the != with !== and I get a different error. I don't see what the problem is with !=. 
The code:

```
func saveContext () {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
        if managedObjectContext != nil { //THIS LINE
            if managedObjectContext.hasChanges && !managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate.
                //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

    // #pragma mark - Core Data stack

    // Returns the managed object context for the application.
    // If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        if _managedObjectContext !== nil {
            let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
            if coordinator != nil { //THIS LINE
                _managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
                _managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
            }
        }
        return _managedObjectContext!
    }
    var _managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil
```

I have a new error: `"'NSManagedObjectContext?' does not have a member named 'hasChanges'"`
In this code:

```
func saveContext () {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
        if managedObjectContext != nil {
            if managedObjectContext.hasChanges && !managedObjectContext.save(&error) { //This line
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate.
                //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @iluvcapra I believe it is of `type NSManagedObjectContext`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is because [NSManagedObjectContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html), and probably NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, do not conform to the [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Equatable.html) protocol. In order to use `==` and `!=`, an object needs to conform to this protocol.

`===` and `!==` do not check equality in that sense. These check to see if two objects are in fact the *same object`. Not with similar values. They both point to the same object in memory.

You are able to check this on the two noted types because they are objects. This should work fine for your situation.

About your second issue, your code should look like this:

```
func saveContext () {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    if let moc = managedObjectContext {
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) { //This line
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate.
            //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

The difference here is `if let moc = managedObjectContext`: if `managedObjectContext` is not nil, the value is stored in the constant `moc`. Otherwise, whatever is inside does not get executed. You can read more about optionals [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_485).

Comment: So I solved these 2 erros but I am now left with another error that seems to be related. I'll put it in the question

Comment: Just put it in question

Answer (score 1):

`self.managedObjectContext` is here typed as an `NSManagedObjectContext`, not an `NSManagedObjectContext?`.

You can't compare a var to nil unless it's of type `Optional<>`, implements `Equatable`, or is nil itself.

Comment: Also could you possibly help me out with this new error I'm having as a result of fixing the past 2? Its in the question